# Run Laravel PHP artisan commands on Google App Engine Flex

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

How to run php artisan commands in Google App Engine Flexible Environment?

Comment: if there is artisan file from laravel then i guess you can run but for that u will need php-fpm install on your machine

Comment: I updated my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59710115/run-laravel-php-artisan-commands-on-google-app-engine-flex/59716955#59716955)

Answer (score 0):

Google's community tutorial **[Run Laravel on App Engine flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible)** will show you how to run artisan commands using GAE flex environment.

GAE will ensure that your Composer dependencies are installed (by running `composer install`) before your application is deployed to Google Cloud. However, there may be some **custom commands that someone may want to execute right after the dependencies are installed**, in your case these would be **Laravel PHP artisan commands.**

Composer's `post-install-cmd` event will be triggered after composer install and  this needs to be added in the `composer.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    // more scripts will be placed here
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache",
        "php artisan config:cache",
    ]
}
```

or as the **[Laravel on App Engine Flex tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible#deploy)** shows:

[image]